# Fluid simulation not baking with fluid object

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation

I've been having a little bit of trouble getting the fluid simulator to cooperate with me.

I have a relatively simple scene setup with plain rectangular objects that are scaled to realistic sizes.

Here's a rough idea of what I'm trying to accomplish: (Ignore the background dirt and grime, I'm just trying to show the scraping action on the machinery.) [image: membrane being scraped]

My plan was to use the fluid simulator and animate the membrane material moving forward and having the top liquid layer scraped off on the edge like in the example photo.
[image: membrane animation]

For some reason, the fluid simulator will not bake correctly and change to a liquid. The domain just remains a rectangle.

I've tried:

- Making the domain bigger or smaller
- Changing the resolution and fluid
  world scene units
- Double checking that scale has been applied to all objects
- Changing directories for where the baked files are stored
  If I just create a small fluid cube and put it inside of a larger cube set to be the domain, I can bake that for whatever that's worth.

I've got a blend-exchange file posted with everything pretty much set to defaults for simplicity.
[image]

Let me know if there's any more information I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of your fluid is too small in comparison to the domain size. There are multiple solutions: Increase the resolution of the fluid (in the domain object), increase the size or dimensions of the fluid (that large, thin rectangle), decrease the size of the domain or a combination of those.

Comment: You seem to be right. Unfortunately, that means I can't get my fluid as thin as I need it to be. Do you have any suggestions of another route I could take to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Try the Mantaflow. You can download it (built-in Blender) from here: http://graphicall.org/ There are a lot of tutorial on YouTube.

Comment: Try an inflow instead of the flat fluid, that scales it down a lot. Make the domain a small as you can, basically only where you see the animation. You can make the water fall through the domain or make an outflow (to prevent it from filling up). And scale the resolution up for your final render. Mantaflow is said to be okey at fluid simulation, a good, but costly alternative is FlipFluids